# Odata Controllrer with ODataQueryOptions generates error in swagger : "undefined /swagger/v1/swagger.json"

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using net core 3.1. My project contains
api controller(ODataController)  that configured in startup  with
UseEndpoints + swagger + odata,

it all works well until i add ODataQueryOptions to one of the methods in the controller.
after that the swagger displays the following error : "undefined /swagger/v1/swagger.json"

those are my startup definitions:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOData();
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
        });

        SetOutputFormatters(services);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.EnableDependencyInjection();
            endpoints.Select().Filter().Expand().MaxTop(10);
            endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
        });

        app.UseSwagger();

        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        });
    }
```

endpoints that supports OData queries.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()

    [HttpGet]
    [ODataRoute]
    [EnableQuery(HandleNullPropagation = HandleNullPropagationOption.False, MaxTop = 100, AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.Select |AllowedQueryOptions.Count)]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Getlist(ODataQueryOptions options)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working demo , you could refer to:

*Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOData();
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
        });

        services.AddMvcCore(options =>
        {
            foreach (var outputFormatter in options.OutputFormatters.OfType<ODataOutputFormatter>().Where(_ => _.SupportedMediaTypes.Count == 0))
            {
                outputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/prs.odatatestxx-odata"));
            }
            foreach (var inputFormatter in options.InputFormatters.OfType<ODataInputFormatter>().Where(_ => _.SupportedMediaTypes.Count == 0))
            {
                inputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/prs.odatatestxx-odata"));
            }
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.EnableDependencyInjection();
            endpoints.Select().Filter().Expand().MaxTop(10);
            endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
        });

        app.UseSwagger();

        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        });
    }

    IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<WeatherForecast>("WeatherForecast");
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

*Controller*

```
[ApiController]
[Route("odata/[controller]/[action]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }


    [HttpGet]
    [ODataRoute]
    [EnableQuery(HandleNullPropagation = HandleNullPropagationOption.False, MaxTop = 100, AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.Select | AllowedQueryOptions.Count)]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Getlist(ODataQueryOptions options)
    { }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! It seems did the trick, but i have several questions : 
1. why do we need to add outputFormatter/inputFormatter ConfigureServices ?
2. Can i inherit from OadaController instead of ControllerBase ?

Comment: @A_G, 1.If you don't  add outputFormatter/inputFormatter in  ConfigureServices method , you will find the specific error: `InvalidOperationException: No media types found in 'Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.ODataInputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes'. Add at least one media type to the list of supported media types.` when  you navigate to `/swagger/v1/swagger.json` or make an debugger.

Comment: 2. If you  inherit from ODataController instead of ControllerBase, you need to add `    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false)]` on the ODataController otherwise you will miss the swagger UI, refer to [this known github issue](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/581).

Comment: @A_G , if you think my solution is helpful ,  could you mark my reply as answer? This will help other people who face the same or similar issue to find the answer quickly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: unfortunately this suggestion doesn't entirely solves this issue, because swaager doesn't recognize and display AllowedQueryOptions that are declared in  EnableQuery attribute.

this is how the api is declared:

[HttpGet][ProducesResponseType(typeof(ODataValue<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)][ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.Select)]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Getlist(ODataQueryOptions options)

Comment: @A_G,  this is a new issue , I suggest you post a new thread for help.

Comment: this is the origin code that i had when the error occurred,  in order to isolate the source of the exception, I tried simplify the example.It is the same issue, because we avoided the error but did not used AllowedQueryOptions  in swagger